# PHPでの画像アップロード時のファイル名変更について

Tags: php

PHPを使用して、カメラで撮影した画像をサーバーへアップロードするプログラムを作っているのですが、アップロードされた画像を確認するとファイル名がimage.jpgで固定されてしまい、新しい画像をアップしても上書きされてしまいます。
　下記のプログラムをどのようにしたら、画像が新しい名前で生成されるようになるのか教えてください。

```
<?php
    //HTMLから画像の受け取り
    $file = $_FILES['my_img'];

    //画像ファイルかどうか判断
    $ext = substr($file['name'], -3);
    if ($ext == 'gif' || $ext == 'GIF' || $ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'JPG' || $ext == 'png' || $ext == 'PNG') {
        $filePath = 'user_img/' . $file['name'];
    //ファイル名を変更している？ 
        $newfilename = date("YmdHis")."-".$_FILES['my_img']['name'];
    //サーバーへアップロード処理 
        move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $filePath);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

ifブロックの中身を次のようにししたらどうですか？

```
$newfilename = date("YmdHis")."-".$_FILES['my_img']['name'];
$filePath = 'user_img/' . $newfilename;
move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $filePath);
```